# No sub-tree in IJ gradle window

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

After opening a java project, by selecting the relevant folder, the project tree shows in the "Project" window. There is also a small blue square on the root folder. But the gradle window is as shown: only the root folder name without any child nodes, tasks etc.

Reload/refresh didn't help.

This is the order of operations:

- Using IDE "Merge mainBranch into myBranch"
- Close IDE and move existing project folder, which did have working Gradle to project-old folder.
- In browser, GitLab, browse to the project folder and "Clone with HTTP" the link
- Create local folder on machine and do `git clone <http link.git>`
- Open the folder in IDE
- Gradle windows is as shown:

[image]

Comment: Assuming it worked before, the "hard reset" is close that window (but not IJ), delete the `.idea/` folder, remove the project from recent projects, and then re-open the project via from the folder.  If you made other changes, perhaps that influenced it, though....  Such as changing settings.gradle?

Comment: @User51 thanks, tried it. added edit to question, may be relevant.

Comment: Is it possible to share project example for investigation? Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?